# Pgpool status restore/reset

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

Need help troubleshooting pgpool issue and reset the status.

The “show pool_nodes” shows node 1 is down:

```
postgres@node-0:~$ psql -p 9999 -c "show pool_nodes"

 node_id |        hostname        | port | status | lb_weight |  role   | select_cnt | load_balance_node | replication_delay | last_status_change
---------+------------------------+------+--------+-----------+---------+------------+-------------------+-------------------+---------------------

 0       |                 node-0 | 5432 | up     | 0.333333  | primary | 245104     | true              | 0                 | 2018-12-03 11:58:49

 1       |                 node-1 | 5432 | down   | 0.666667  | standby | 198341     | false             | 0                 | 2019-01-30 09:02:54

(2 rows)
```

I can access both node 0 and node 1 from pgpool:

```
postgres@node-0:~$ psql -h node-0
psql (10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-1.pgdg16.04+1))
Type "help" for help.
postgres=# \q

postgres@node-0:~$ psql -h node-1
psql (10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-1.pgdg16.04+1))
Type "help" for help.
postgres=# \q
```

From the syslog, I found the following event happened:

> Jan 30 09:02:54 node-0 pgpool[7565]: 2019-01-30 09:02:54: pid 13516:
>   DETAIL:  postmaster on DB node 1 was shutdown by administrative
>   command
>
> Jan 30 09:02:54 node-0 pgpool[7565]: 2019-01-30 09:02:54: pid 13516:
>   LOG:  received degenerate backend request for node_id: 1 from pid
>   [13516]
>
> Jan 30 09:02:54 node-0 pgpool[7565]: 2019-01-30 09:02:54: pid 7565:
>   LOG:  Pgpool-II parent process has received failover request
>
> Jan 30 09:02:54 node-0 pgpool[7565]: 2019-01-30 09:02:54: pid 7565:
>   LOG:  starting degeneration. shutdown host node-1(5432)
>
> Jan 30 09:02:54 node-0 pgpool[7565]: 2019-01-30 09:02:54: pid 7565:
>   LOG:  Do not restart children because we are switching over node id 1
>   host: node-1 port: 5432 and we are in streaming replication mode
>
> Jan 30 09:02:54 node-0 pgpool[7565]: 2019-01-30 09:02:54: pid 7565:
>   LOG:  child pid 13516 needs to restart because pool 1 uses backend 1
>   Jan 30 09:02:54 node-0 pgpool[7565]: 2019-01-30 09:02:54: pid 7565:
>   LOG:  failover: set new primary node: 0
>
> Jan 30 09:02:54 node-0 pgpool[7565]: 2019-01-30 09:02:54: pid 7565:
>   LOG:  failover: set new master node: 0

Comment: Could you try `pcp_detach_node`, then `pcp_attach_node` ?

Comment: @LuanHuynh

Got this error when detaching node 1:

`ERROR:  invalid degenerate backend request, node id : 1 status: [3] is not valid for failover`

Comment: @LuanHuynh I think status=3 means that node has already been detached.  pcp_attache_node works!

`postgres@sf-preprod-pgpool-01:~$ pcp_attach_node -h localhost -p 9898 -n 1
Password:
pcp_attach_node -- Command Successful`